# How to padding digit after floating point in bash

Tags: bash

I have input file contains contents as follows

```
0.0 0.0 98.0 91.0
145.525 72.62 243.525 163.63
```

I want output as

```
0.000 0.000 98.000 91.000
145.525 72.620 243.525 163.630
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please add 3 simple things in your post too. 1- sample of Input in code tags, 2- sample of output in code tags and 3- effort whatever you tried to solve this problem and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=sprintf("%0.3f", $i)}}1' file
```

See manual [`sprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_13)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with sed, It's not mathematic but ...

```
sed -E ':A;s/([0-9]*\.[0-9]{1,2})( |$)/\10\2/;tA' infile
```